# Linux script backing up data and copying files to another server

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I want to write a Cent OS script backing up data and copying files to another server every day.

I want to set up a script that would dump the DB and then, once that is done, copy the dump file to another server.

As I understand, I need to set up a file that would list those commands and then add it into crontab.

Where I'm stuck is how to write that file, as I'm not familiar with Linux server commands. Would it be something like that below? What could I fix?

```
#!/bin/sh
backupscript -r ~/path/to/db ~/path/to/backup
sshpass -f "/path/to/passwordfile" scp -r /some/local/path user@example.com:/some/remote/path
```

But how will `scp` know when to run after backupscript is over?

Comment: Maybe start by learning the basics of shell scripting?

Comment: @Mansuro great advice! That's what I'm doing, no?

Comment: By asking questions on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Mansuro well, even science proceeds by asking questions. It's the best way to learn. And I'm quite surprised you are willing to spend your time on writing patronizing comments in mentoring tone rather than helping others to learn. If you did not like the question, minus it, and spend your valuable time on something of more value to everyone.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/144481/18098

Comment: @Mansuro I appreciate your help!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this type of script to backup and scp. i hope this will help you to create script.

**DB backup script**

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -uroot -proot@123 dbname > /opt/db_dumps/dbname.sql
```

**SCP script**

```
#!/bin/bash

scp /opt/backups/dbname.sql root@10.200.172.46:/opt/db_dumps/
ssh root@10.200.172.46 /opt/db_dumps/dbname.sql
```